# Jenkins Active Directory broke. Cannot login, No valid crumb

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm running Jenkins on Debian buster for nearly two years in a secure network and I use LDAP/Active Directory for authentication.

A few days ago Jenkins had some notifications that a new version of Jenkins was available and a bunch of plugins should be upgraded including the Active Directory plugin.  I started the installation of the plugins, waited for everything to stabilize, then ran:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

Now when I try to login to jenkins I get:

```
HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
```

Even if I try this manually:

```
$ curl -v -X GET http://jenkins-url:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json --user user:password
{
  "_class":"hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer",
  "crumb":"2eacfe24ff306c0c68211736cf3c02d3c9e5d675800aec59002ffdc9bcc28301",
  "crumbRequestField":"Jenkins-Crumb"
}
$ curl -X POST http://jenkins-url:8080/job/a330-latest/build --user user:password -H 'Jenkins-Crumb: 2eacfe24ff306c0c68211736cf3c02d3c9e5d675800aec59002ffdc9bcc28301'
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
```

How do I troubleshoot this?  `/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword` is no longer available and there is no jenkins internal user database.

Comment: Failing to recover the machine, I've started building a new server from scratch.  I'd also accept any answer that suggests how to copy project configurations from one jenkins instance to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugins probably hadn't finished installing when you ran `sudo apt upgrade`.

In `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`, set `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>` and `systemctl restart jenkins`.

Now when you load the jenkins webpage, you'll have administration rights without the need to log-in.

At this point go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Manage Plugins" and make sure that all plugins are updated.  Restart jenkins if necessary after upgrading everything (if ldap/AD plugins are updated, you MUST restart jenkins.

Next, go to "Manage Jenkins">"Configure Global Security" and re-add your active-directory or LDAP settings.  Be sure to use the "Test Domain" function to ensure it works.

Try logging in to ensure that your AD connection is working.

If all is successful, then finally go to "Manage Jenkins">"Configure Global Security" and remake your "Authorization" requirements.  It's probably on "Anyone can do anything", so flip it back over to Matrix-based security (or whatever you want) and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has the same issue, the "*Oh Sh$t Im Locked out*" section from the link below worked for me.

I a nutshell, edit **$JENKINS_HOME/config.xml** and change
`<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to `false

Reference: https://sqlnotesfromtheunderground.wordpress.com/2017/01/27/connecting-jenkins-to-active-directory-and-how-to-reset-access-to-jenkins/